# How to get the Application id of an assembly

Tags: c#, client-certificates

SO lately i have been struggling to get owin package to run with https. After discovering owin.forcehttps it still doesn't work, however since i learned that even for testing and localhost certificates are required i searched on how ti install a certificate and bind it to that application.
So far i think i have found the right resource for that, however it says that you bind ip and port to thumbprint of the cert and the application id which looks kinda obvious to me.

At this point i'm struggling on how to get the application id.
When googling you can get it trough file explorer and or trough powershell but this only seems to work with installed apps. Since this is going to be a module of an application and not an installable application how am i able to get an application id of the exe (which will be reference to the main application)? I already signed my assembly.

Edit:

resource to binding ssl certificate
[binding ssl certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Do you want the GUID?  In VS under Properties : Build : Assembly Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the http.sys application ID field?  If so, it is not used. Just make up a random GUID.

For example:

```
$"appid={Guid.NewGuid()}"
```

I think the intent of the field is to act as a sentinel to the owning application. For example, imagine two applications both trying to “own” the same port. If the config tool from one is used, but doesn’t find its hard coded appid, it can alert that the config has been changed by a different app.

Comment: I don't know about that microsoft docs state that guid is different from application id

Comment: i'll link my microsoft docs for binding certificate which uses the appid

Comment: Yeah. That is http.sys. It is not used by the system. Note from your link “The appid parameter is a GUID that **can** be used to identify the owning application.”

Comment: ah great and how do i give my application a guid, i have seen in the properties or asembly information there is a field for guid, can i just paste a random guid in there and use that to bind the ssl?

Comment: Assembly information is for COM and other things.  In this case, you literally just make it up.  You can hardcode an arbitrary value without issue.